# how to center all columns with bootstrap-sass relative to screen size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-sass

The entire Rails app can be viewed on [GitHub](https://github.com/adam-wanninger/cloud_contacts)
and the app is hosted [on heroku](http://contactually-slim.herokuapp.com/)

Update: I have roughly centered the columns (take a look at the link), but I would like to center them in relation to the `Contacts` title. Is this possible?

Edit: Bonus points: each contact has links to `Show` `Edit` and `Destroy`. These are currently sort of smooshed together as `ShowEditDestroy`, and I would love to know how to put some padding in between them so they don't look so smooshed.

I am trying to center all columns within my view. I have done this previously using `zurb-foundation`, but I am having trouble doing it with `bootstrap-sass`. Here is an example of a previous site that I have built with `zurb-foundation`, that I am trying to mimic using `bootstrap-sass`: [my portfolio](http://adamwanninger.com)

I just want all the guts in my view to organize themselves neatly within columns in botstrap, but to stay centered relative to the middle of the page, while keeping text right centered at all time.

Here is my current `index.html.erb` view:

```
<div id="main-container" class="container" style="text-align: left">
  <div class="row">
        <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

        <h1 class="text-center">Listing Contacts</h1>

        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <div id="content" class="col-xs-3">
              <th>First name</th>
              </div>
                <div id="content" class="col-xs-4">
              <th>Last name</th>
                </div>
                  <div id="content" class="col-xs-5">
              <th>Email address</th>
                  </div>
                    <div id="content" class="col-xs-6">
              <th>Company Name</th>
                    </div>
                      <div id="content" class="col-xs-7">
              <th>Phone Number</th>
                      </div>
                        <div id="content" class="col-xs-8">
              <th colspan="3"></th>
                        </div>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= contact.first_name %></td>
                <td><%= contact.last_name %></td>
                <td><%= contact.email_address %></td>
                <td><%= contact.company_name %></td>
                <td><%= contact.phone_number %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Show', contact %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(contact) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', contact, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <br>

        <%= link_to 'New Contact', new_contact_path %>

        <h2>Import Contacts</h2>

        <%= form_tag import_contacts_path, multipart: true do %>
            <%= file_field_tag :file %>
            <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, i'm just building an online contact list, by following railscast 396. I just want to make everything purdy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap-sass does have a few mixins that you can use, one of these is a [centered block](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_center-block.scss). You can use it like this (once you have boostrap-sass up and running)

```
@import "bootstrap";

.centered {
  @include center-block();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. What exactly is a `mixin` when defined in the context of your answer?

Comment: It's a sass slab of css that you can reuse in your own (SASS)CSS files. This article gives you a 2sec overview of it: http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions  You will need to be running your CSS through SASS though (so have the extension as .scss)

Comment: Thanks @FuzzyJulz, I am using the `.scss` extension. Your answer has certainly helped, but I could use a bit more help if you don't mind. Please see the update in my OP, and the link to the hosted demo of this app. http://contactually-slim.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Looks like you have pretty much figured this one out now. I noticed you were using the bootstrap classes incorrectly before - remember all columns in a container should add up to 12 ( so where you have classes of col-xs-)  Also if you set the width of your <table> to 100% it gets rid of the gap on the right side.